# When is the order of magnitude not equal to the exponent of scientific notation?

Tags: units, notation, dimensional-analysis, error-analysis, order-of-magnitude

Explain why the order of magnitude is sometimes not the same as the exponent in scientific notation. It is because of the units?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the exact *definition* of order of magnitude. 
It is defined as the logarithm (base 10) rounded to the nearest whole number (see [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude)). Thus, all numbers between $\sqrt{10}\cdot 10^{m-1}$ and $\sqrt{10}\cdot 10^{m}$ have $m$ as order of magnitude, even though, for example, $4\cdot 10^{m-1}$ has $m-1$ as exponent of $10$ in scientific notation ($4 > \sqrt{10}=3.1622...$).

Comment: I know what you're trying to say, but the example isn't well written. In particular, $0.5>\sqrt{10}$ is obviously false.

Comment: @DavidHammen  Thanks! Sometimes one is thinking something and writing something else!

Answer (score -3):

$n \,e \,m$ is just usually thought of as $n \times 10^m$, coming from the early age of computers/pocket calculators, it's a historical way of writing the scientific notation. On the contrary, $n \times e^m$ is just that, it is never written as $n \,e \,m$.